# Javascript Popstate event prevent Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

i had a problem about preventing ajax request on Popstate event.

so, this is my code :

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
        var state = e.originalEvent.state;
            if (state !== null) {


    loadProducts(location.pathname);
        }

});

function loadProducts(url) {

    $.ajax({
            type        : "GET", 
            url         : url, 
            dataType    : "html",
            cache       : true,
            success     : function(checks) {
                            $(".ajaxpage").html(checks);
                    }
            });
}; 

$('#product').on("click", ".paging a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href')); 
    loadProducts($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

pushstate event works really well with ajax request. but when i hit "back button" the page will do the same ajax request again. why is that? i don't need ajax anymore cause i already visit that page? just like what Github does?

how to prevent that ajax request on popstate event?

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to change your code to cache old requests and reuse the responses.

Comment: did u mean change cache to false or remove it? and what's reuse response?

Comment: You need to write code to store previous responses so you can skip the request entirely.  Beware that the request may not have finished yet; you should use promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
var state = e.originalEvent.state
```

You should access the state by writing

```
var state = e.state
```

For reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Comment: thanks Luddd3 for answering, i try ur method. the address url bar was change. still requesting ajax.